# Laravel 5.3 large file upload

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.3, ovh

I have an issue to upload large file size with laravel 5.3 on ovh mutualized server ?

I have the following message :
" The connection has been reset.
Try the suggestions below:
Check connection
Check proxy and firewall
Run Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

How can I handle it please ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is probably not a Laravel problem, but a PHP limitation on uploading large files. So you have to configure your **php.ini** file to allow larger files, and, maybe give it more time to upload your files:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```